# Creating custom loss for continous conditional random field

Tags: python, keras, crf

I am currently trying to implement the network presented in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXPlC.png) using Keras. The model can be divided into two parts: the first one, called the super pixels depth network, regresses depth values for an image segmented in super pixels while the second one is a continuous conditional random field layer whose goal is to ensure spatial and temporal consistency in the depth maps predicted for each frame of a video. Each part has its set of parameters, W for the super pixel network and alpha_s & alpha_t for the CRF. Both are trained jointly using stochastic gradient descent.

I had no problem implementing the super pixels depth network, it’s just the first 31 layers of VGG-16 followed by a super pixels pooling layer. The tricky part for me is the CRF layer and the following loss function:

[image: loss function expression]

In this equation:

- I is a frame from a video.
- d is a Nx1 vector of ground truth super pixels depth where N is the number of super pixels in the video.
- L is a NxN matrix depending on alpha_s, alpha_t and the spatio-temporal relations between super pixels given by the segmentation algorithm.
- Z is a Nx1 vector of estimated super pixels depth depending on W.

If I am not mistaken, this loss function does not have the conventional form “loss(y_true, y_pred)" and uses y_true (d in the expression) and the network weights (in z and L). My idea is to use the functional API and write a custom loss function that computes -log P( d | I ) but I am wondering how the gradients will be computed? I read [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2662) that Keras is taking care of gradients computation as long as we are only using existing operations but matrix inversion is not in the tensorflow backend. Will it work if I call tf.matrix_inverse?

Best regards,
Ambroise

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXPlC.png) Zhao, Xu-Ran, Xun Wang, and Qi-Chao Chen. "Temporally Consistent Depth Map Prediction Using Deep Convolutional Neural Network and Spatial-Temporal Conditional Random Field." Journal of Computer Science and Technology 32.3 (2017): 443-456. [link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11390-017-1735-x)